# How to create a Quickcheck Arbitrary of a struct containing a reference?

Tags: rust, quickcheck

The Rust [quickcheck documentation](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/quickcheck/trait.Arbitrary.html) notes that for any type implementing `Arbitrary`

> They must also be sendable and static since every test is run in its own thread using thread::Builder::spawn, which requires the Send + 'static bounds.

If I need to generate data for a struct that contains a reference how do I go about doing that? For instance:

```
#![cfg_attr(test, feature(plugin))]
#![cfg_attr(test, plugin(quickcheck_macros))]

#[cfg(test)]
extern crate quickcheck;

#[cfg(test)]
use quickcheck::{Arbitrary,Gen};

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[derive(Debug,Clone)]
pub struct C<'a> {
    s: &'a str,
    b: bool
}

#[cfg(test)]
impl<'a> Arbitrary for C<'a> {
    fn arbitrary<G: Gen>(g: &mut G) -> C<'a> {
        let s = g.gen::<&str>();
        C{s: s, b: (s.len() > 0)}
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[quickcheck]
    fn len_checks_out(c: C) -> bool {
        (c.s.len() > 0) == c.b
    }
}
```

fails with

```
cargo test
   Compiling qcq v0.1.0 (file:///Users/blt/projects/us/troutwine/qcquestion)
src/lib.rs:18:10: 18:19 error: the type `C<'a>` does not fulfill the required lifetime [E0477]
src/lib.rs:18 impl<'a> Arbitrary for C<'a> {
                       ^~~~~~~~~
note: type must outlive the static lifetime
error: aborting due to previous error
Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: Could not compile `qcq`.
```

This is a somewhat contrived example but it's in the same spirit as the originating problem. The lifetime annotations work out except but under test.

Comment: You can't. The `'static` bound means implementations of `Arbitrary` cannot contain borrowed data. This restriction may be lifted once `panic::recover` (or whatever name it ends up being) is stabilized, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Ah, okay, well that's pretty definite answer. The stabilization discussion is [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27719)? Is the only reason this limitation exists as the documentation states, owing to running each test in its own thread? If tests were run serially, would the limitation be lifted or would there be a follow-on complication?

Comment: Also, thank you for the super useful testing library! :)

Comment: @troutwine Won't `impl Arbitrary for C<'statc>` work? In any case an `Arbitrary` instance for non static data doesn't make much sense either way. Consider the call to `g.gen::<&str>()` which won't compile as there is no implementation of `Rand` for `&str` (what could that &str be except a static string?).

Comment: @Mar very likely I need to hit the docs again. This is motivated by my first non-toy Rust project. What I'm doing is writing QC test to validate a parser, property being that `parse . format` ought to be identity, cribbing Haskell syntax a bit. Have need to generate arbitrary struct instances which contain &str. Suppose that this is fundamentally flawed, though, as they won't be the _same_ references anyhow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this for two reasons. First, `Arbitrary` has a `'static` bound, which means that the types that implement `Arbitrary` may not have references, unless their lifetime is `'static`. This ensures that instances don't refer to objects that they don't "own".

Second, in order to return a `C<'a>` where `'a` is anything other than `'static`, most of the time you'll also need a parameter that contains a reference with the same lifetime parameter (it's not always necessary, e.g. when the field using the lifetime parameter can be initialized later, but that doesn't apply here). Therefore, you'd need a function defined a bit like this:

```
fn arbitrary<'a, G: Gen>(g: &'a mut G) -> C<'a> {
    let s = g.gen::<&str>();
    C { s: s, b: (s.len() > 0) }
}
```

(Note that `'a` is defined on the function, not on the `impl`.)

There are two big problems with this:

- `Arbitrary::arbitrary()` returns `Self`. This means that the function must return the type on which `Arbitrary` is implemented. Here, however, `C<'a>` depends on a lifetime parameter defined *on the function*; `C<'a>` cannot possibly be the same as the `impl` target, since that type cannot use that lifetime parameter.
- `Rng::gen()` simply calls [`Rand::rand()`](http://burntsushi.net/rustdoc/rand/trait.Rand.html#tymethod.rand), which also returns `Self`, and thus suffers from the same problem as `Arbitrary::arbitrary()`. Also, `Rand` is not implemented for `&str` (or even for `String`).

What can you do then? Instead of storing a `&str` in your struct, you should store a `String`. This makes your struct `'static`, and you can use the implementation of `Arbitrary` for `String` to generate test values.

But what if you don't want to use `String` in your actual application code? You can make your struct generic by accepting either `&str` or `String`. There are two traits in the standard library that help you do this: [`AsRef`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) and [`Borrow`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html). Here's an example using `Borrow`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct C<S: Borrow<str>> {
    s: S,
    b: bool
}
```

Now, you can use either `C<&str>` or `C<String>`, depending on what's needed. Obviously, you can't implement `Arbitrary` for `C<&str>`, but you can implement it for `C<String>`. Actually, why not implement it for all types that implement `Arbitrary`?

```
impl<S: Borrow<str> + Arbitrary> Arbitrary for C<S> {
    fn arbitrary<G: Gen>(g: &mut G) -> C<S> {
        let s: S = Arbitrary::arbitrary(g);
        let b = s.borrow().len() > 0;
        C { s: s, b: b }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tremendously helpful! Thank you very much!